# Backbone - bind multiple views on one $el (events are duplicated)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a container `.js-todoslist` for todo lists. Also I have several views `TodosListView` for each todolist. All `TodosListView`'s are created from parent view and binded **to the same el** `.js-todoslist`.

Todos lists are not rendered on initialize, I need to render different Todos' lists by clicking buttons so each list has `showTodolist` method that shows it.

The problem is, though at the moment only **one** list can be rendered, **all** of them are actually initialized. And when I press `.add-btn` in rendered List, **all lists have `add` function trigged (not only current rendered).**

```
TodosListView = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    "click .add-btn": "add"

  initialize: (options) ->
    self = this
    @model = @options.model

    # I've tried to undelegate event after initialize, but no luck
    # @$el.undelegate('.add-btn', 'click');
    # @undelegateEvents()

  # show this todolist
  showTodolist: ->
    @$el.html @template(@model.toJSON())

  render: ->
    @

  add: ->
    console.log "Add to Todos list #" + @model.get("id")
```

How to avoid this (excpt creating different views for each list)? Thanks.

Comment: Try setElement method of backbone

Comment: @meshuai, you mean after invoking `showTodolist` use setElement for specifying el property?

Comment: after render diff todo list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that since you are using the same el for different views, when you render a view it does not unbind the events of the previous view.

Before rendering the view, use:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
```